# "The" and superlative of uncountable noun — "the clearest water"?

Tags: articles, definite-articles, uncountable-nouns, superlative-degree

Uncountable nouns are usually used without an article. Superlatives require definite article. What comes out of these 2 rules when superlative meets uncountable article?

We need an example, I hope it is good:

> This lake has clear water.
>
> This lake has clearest water.
>
> This lake has the clearest water.

When I searched the web I found both "clearest water" and "the clearest water".

I read on this site, that in informal speech *the* is frequently omitted, so let's concentrate on formal speech or writing. If there is Am/Br specific it would also be interesting. Please comment on the examples and in general. Thanks.

Comment: Lose #2. I can't think of any context where that wording would sound natural. The other two are fine; Barrie's done a good job of explaining #3.

Comment: When you searched the web and found "clearest water", what was the context? Please give examples of what you found. Show the results of your research.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Superlatives describe a particular quality to the highest degree when compared to the same quality found elsewhere. So, we might say *The water in the other two lakes is really quite clear, but I’d say this lake has **the clearest water**.*

However, the superlative can also describe an absolute, with something like the sense of *very*. So we might also say *Oh, look at that lake. Did you ever see anything like it? It has **the clearest water**.*

In normal use, the definite article is part of the superlative form.

Comment: The last sentence makes it complete answer :)

Comment: @Barrie: There is at least one counter-example - as you qualify though, it is therefore hardly normal usage. **Best practice** has become so fixed an expression that it doesn't take an article (except when used as a count noun; Wikipedia defines  **a** _best practice_).

Answer (score 2):

Uncountable nouns in English do not use an indefinite article. Definite articles are commonly used with uncountable nouns.
Superlatives also don't use an indefinite article.  I think your source of information did not clarify this, which resulted in your question.

Comment: Also, if you substitute 'fish' for 'water', the same rules will apply.  Though you might want to change you adjective to 'big'.

Comment: Good point, Mike. After correcting my approach to uncountable nouns and the articles, the answer becomes obvious. And I learnt even more than I expected.

Answer (score 1):

One has to be very careful when using results from a simple web search. I tried the parameters "clearest water" -"the clearest water" and found, in the first 20 hits on Google:

**false results**:

Which place in the Caribbean do you think has the Prettiest and Clearest Water ?

Home Med's clearest water

**captions** (condensed formatting) , including:

Clearest water in Door County Wi, Lake Michigan side

Clearest Water

Favourite / best beaches for / to  clearest water / ...

Waffle sandwich; Almost Swimming Season; Clearest Water in New Zealand; Queen Charlotte Cove; Shout Out to Brooklyn

**'web formatting'** (condensed formatting) , including:

B&Bs/beach w/clearest water/other

**informal wordings** (condensed and not accepted grammar):

Clearest Water ive ever had in my tank! - YouTube

I we're going to *concentrate on formal speech or writing*, we can't cite raw web data as evidence of usage.

Comment: So in captions you are allowed to omit *the*?

Comment: @Jarek  Yes. Much like tweets today, captions, headlines, telegrams (if you're old enough to remember telegrams) and other such texts where there is limited space or a cost for exceeding a certain letter or word count are often highly elliptical.

Comment: @Jarek, StoneyB's comment is spot on. The word "the" seems to be implied (an unwritten ellipsis) in a caption like "Clearest Water I've ever had..."